# QModbus in a thread produces errors in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a worker thread (QThread) which is collecting data from instruments that are connected either by RS232 (which is working fine, it's easy to implement). The other instrument is connect by RS485 and uses the Modbus protocol, but so it looks the QModbus is itself running in a separate thread which makes it necessary to connect the answer signal from QModbus to a slot which is then collecting the answer from QModbus, so I have to wait until this slot is called and executed, for that I have to make sure that my thread enters into the event loop that my slot can be called, I did this that way:

```
do
{
    QEventLoop(this).processEvents();
} while (!answerReceived);
```

But this produces me tons of such error messages in QtCreator:

```
QBasicTimer::start: Timers cannot be started from another thread
```

I've tried also these two suggestions from here:
[How to tell QThread to wait until work is done ,and then finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610785/how-to-tell-qthread-to-wait-until-work-is-done-and-then-finish) but unfortunately I still get these error. What can I do to get rid of these errors or do I have to live with this?

---

**Update.**
Here the code of the involved functions:

```
void Worker::requestValue(int address, int length)
{
    answerReceived = false;
    qDebug() << "Read values";
    read(address, length);
    do
    {
        QEventLoop(this).processEvents();
    } while (!answerReceived);
}

void Worker::read(int address, int length)
{
    if (!modbusDevice)
        return;
    if (auto *reply = modbusDevice->sendReadRequest(readRequest(address, length), 10)) {
        if (!reply->isFinished())
            connect(reply, &QModbusReply::finished, this, &Worker::onReceiveValues);
        else
            delete reply; // broadcast replies return immediately
    } else {
        qDebug() << tr("Read error: ") + modbusDevice->errorString();
    }
}

void Worker::onReceiveValues()
{
    auto reply = qobject_cast<QModbusReply *>(sender());
    if (!reply)
        return;

if (reply->error() == QModbusDevice::NoError) {
    const QModbusDataUnit unit = reply->result();
    QVector<quint16> receivedValues = unit.values();
    switch(answerType)
    {
    case AnswerType::Flow:
    {
        prominentPumvValues.flow = processFloatValue(receivedValues);
    }
        break;
    case AnswerType::Stroke:
    {
        prominentPumvValues.stroke = processFloatValue(receivedValues);
    }
        break;
    case AnswerType::Frequency:
        prominentPumvValues.frequency = receivedValues.at(0);
        break;
    case AnswerType::SerialNumber:
    {
        prominentPumvValues.serialNumber = processString(receivedValues);
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
} else if (reply->error() == QModbusDevice::ProtocolError) {
    qDebug() << tr("Read response error: %1 (Mobus exception: 0x%2)").
                                arg(reply->errorString()).
                                arg(reply->rawResult().exceptionCode(), -1, 16);
} else {
    qDebug() << tr("Read response error: %1 (code: 0x%2)").
                                arg(reply->errorString()).
                                arg(reply->error(), -1, 16);
}

reply->deleteLater();
answerReceived = true;
}
```

I've found this thread here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/82819/qbasictimer-start-timers-cannot-be-started-from-another-thread-issue/10 and modified the read function as follows:

```
void Worker::read(int address, int length)
{
    if (!modbusDevice)
        return;
    if (auto *reply = modbusDevice->sendReadRequest(readRequest(address, length), 10)) {
        if (!reply->isFinished())
        {
            qDebug() << "Reply not finished";
            qDebug() << "Connect: " << connect(reply, &QModbusReply::finished, [reply, this]() {
                qDebug() << "connect";
                if(reply->error() == QModbusClient::NoError)
                {
                    const QModbusDataUnit unit = reply->result();
                    receivedValues = unit.values();
                    qDebug() << "Lambda: " << receivedValues.length();
                }
                else
                    qDebug() << "Reply error";
                reply->deleteLater();
                qDebug() << "Bye";
            });
            qDebug() << "Ade";
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Reply finished";
            delete reply; // broadcast replies return immediately
        }
    } else {
        qDebug() << tr("Read error: ") + modbusDevice->errorString();
    }
    qDebug() <<receivedValues[0] << receivedValues[1];
}
```

The answer of connect is true but so it looks the code inside the lambda is not executed, there is no output of the qDebug() functions inside the lambda

Comment: You need to show your code. How do you create QModbus object, how you connect signals/slots to it

Comment: Finally I found this here [link](https://forum.qt.io/topic/82819/qbasictimer-start-timers-cannot-be-started-from-another-thread-issue) and I tried to implement a lambda function just for testing but the code in this function is not executed ("hello World"), but the answer of connect is true: 'code' qDebug() << connect(reply, &QModbusReply::finished, [reply, this](){qDebug() << "hello World";});

Comment: You need to provide your code